# Getting error by using NopCommerce services in WCF Project

Tags: wcf, rest, nopcommerce

I am using existing NopCommerce services in WCF project for my mobile application, after hosting in local IIS server, and by browsing, I am getting Exception as follows...

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is `'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: instance'`. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

> at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterInstance[T](ContainerBuilder
>   builder, T instance) at
>   Nop.Core.Infrastructure.DependencyManagement.ContainerManager.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4(ContainerBuilder
>   x) at
>   Nop.Core.Infrastructure.DependencyManagement.ContainerManager.UpdateContainer(Action`1
>   action) at
>   Nop.Core.Infrastructure.DependencyManagement.ContainerConfigurer.Configure(IEngine
>   engine, ContainerManager containerManager, NopConfig configuration) at
>   Nop.Core.Infrastructure.EngineContext.CreateEngineInstance(NopConfig
>   config) at Nop.Core.Infrastructure.EngineContext.Initialize(Boolean
>   forceRecreate) at Nop.Core.Infrastructure.EngineContext.get_Current()
>   at NopServicesTest.AuthService..ctor() at
>   CreateNopServicesTest.AuthService() at
>   System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(Message
>   message) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.EnsureServiceInstance(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added [WcfIntegration of AUtofac](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration)?